# Why use Java as a server-side language over an interpreted language?

Tags: java, compiler, web, interpreters, runtime

Web pages are usually tested by refreshing the page, clicking some UI component, then either writing to a debug log or adding some breakpoints in the IDE... in larger applications, unit tests are written to guarantee the output of the program, etc.

It seems like Java is an awful server-side language for a web page. You have to recompile **every time** you modify any line of code and pass the built `EAR` or `WAR` to the application server... something like Python or PHP (or any other interpreted language) would execute at run-time, removing the need for compilation before testing.

**My question**: what is the justification to using Java as a server-side language? Why is it better to use than an interpreted language?

Comment: You'd still need to package and upload your Python application to the server, and the compile time is not exactly a problem in Java, so I fail to see the issue. As long as you have a robust deployment process, there's really no overhead to using Java, everything should be done automatically.

Comment: @VincentSavard Right now, I have to build (which takes 10 minutes), once it finished building, I have to start/stop the server and point it towards the EAR/WAR. Therefore, testing one line of code takes 10+ mintues

Comment: Seems like a flaw in your process, not in the programming language.

Comment: @VincentSavard If that's the case, how does a compiled language get tested without having to recompile? Not following here.. Java has to recompile to be able to run the code. If I change one line in the `.java` file, it has to be recompiled, plain and simple

Comment: Either you have an enormously large `.java` file, or you haven't figured out how to sensibly separate your code using libraries.  You shouldn't have to recompile an entire project just to change one line of code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was trying to over-simplify; we have `ant` doing these builds, and it takes forever.

Comment: Then your strategy must be to test that line of code before it ever gets to the `ant` job.  The `ant` job, therefore, only has to run one time per release, prior to your integration testing or whatever the next phase in your development process is.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. There is no such thing as an "interpreted language". A language is a mathematical specification, a set of rules and restrictions, a piece of paper. It is neither compiled nor interpreted. It just *is*. Compilation and interpretation are traits of a compiler or interpreter (duh!), not a language. Every language can be implemented by a compiler, and every language can be implemented by an interpreter. There are interpreters for C and C++. There are compilers for ECMAScript, Python, PHP, and Ruby.

Comment: In fact, you mention using Python and PHP to circumvent compilation, but actually, *all existing implementations of both Python and PHP use compilers*. It is *impossible* to use Python or PHP without compiling it, unless you write a new implementation that is purely interpreted. CPython, PyPy, Jython, IronPython, Pyston, Zend Engine, P8, Quercus, Peachpie, all the ECMAScript implementations, all Ruby implementations except the no longer maintained MRI, they all have at least one compiler, some even have more than one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag "There's no such thing as an interpreted language"... oh? really? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language

Comment: You do realize the irony of pointing to an article which starts with the words "this article has multiple issues" and continues in the second paragraph by essentially stating that the term makes no sense, right?

Comment: @KolabCanyon I think you're confused. Bad build/deplyment systems (which is fashionable these days to bitch about) would make even Python and JavaScript to have the same trouble as Java. I once built a C based Web app for a router and I could test it really fast (less than a minute) despite being a bloated web app. Do some sleuthing and find the real root cause than blaming language itself.

Comment: Every single Python implementation that is in current use today, as well as every single Python implementation that was ever created in the entire history of Python, always had compilers. In the entire history of Python, there has not been a single fully interpreted implementation. So, is Python compiled or interpreted? Cint is an interpreter for C. So, is C compiled or interpreted?

Comment: @JörgWMittag you're acting like it is a made up term. It literally means "Compiled at run-time", as in, I don't have to explicitly compile my program.. Java is compiled and PHP is interpreted... I'm not saying PHP doesn't use a compiler to convert to machine code... any language needs that step

Comment: I am intrigued. If you define "interpreted" to mean "compiled at runtime", then what do you call something that is interpeted?

Comment: @JörgWMittag PHP. Do you notice in PHP how no extra `.class` file gets spit out or `.exe`, but simply runs the program in memory at run-time

Comment: I expect that interpreted languages run moderately slower if the page is essentially getting recompiled every time it's loaded.

Comment: How is recompiling every time the code is changed worse than recompiling every time the code is run?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: because the Java stack spends more time on up-front compilation, more time starting the JVM, more time initializing the non-lazy Spring beans, initializing Hibernate mappings, etc. all to maximize throughput in production. Other stacks are lazier. They are slower in production but get the first page on the screen much more quickly.

Comment: @kevincline Those are mostly characteristics of popular frameworks, not the languages themselves.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede It is when you're testing. I agree when  the product is deployed, it is better to have a compiled language

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the title of your question which is a valid one and then there is the content of the question which contains some poor assumptions and/or incorrect statements.  I'll address the body first:

> You have to recompile every time you modify any line of code and pass the built EAR or WAR to the application server...

Not true.  First of all, [technology exists for Java](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/jrebel-101-what-jrebel-is-and-how-it-makes-java-development-lightning-fast/) which allows you to modify code and have it change a running application without even restarting the application.  I link to the product not to endorse it but rather as proof.  I have used it and can verify that it works.  Secondly, python must also be compiled.  It's just when that compilation occurs.  In java you do it ahead up front.  In python it happens at runtime (the details may vary depending on the Python variant)

As far as why one would use a pre-compiled language, here are a few reasons off the top of my head

- bytecode files are smaller than source files and servers (not being human) don't need source.
- Compiling ahead of time allows you to catch syntactical errors.  Why wait until you've loaded your file on the server to find out that you forgot a colon?

The rest of the reasons around why you would choose one over the other really aren't about when you compile.  They tend to center around dynamic versus static code and the advantages and disadvantages between the two approaches.  I would expect well written Java code to be faster than well written Python though this is a factor that can change over time in both actual speed and whether it matters.

Comment: It sounds like  you *have* to use JRebel to get a workable development environment. That's really the frustration, is I may not be able to use any product I so desire depending on the licensing

Comment: @KolobCanyon I have no idea why your builds take so long.  The fact that you are using ant implies your build environment is antiquated but that still doesn't explain it.  Is there a reason you don't test locally?  I typically just save and run.  The time to build and start a simple app is a few seconds or less.  My guess is you have code generation or something like that going on.  I would say though that if you can't fix your builds, that might be a tool to consider.  It's relatively cheap and works well for "refresh the page" test cycle.

Comment: @KolobCanyon It sounds like a legacy project but another thing that vastly improves the Java server side experience is using an 'embedded' web server as opposed to build ears and wars and all that.  If you are up to your ears (pun intended) in the old web model it can be hard to shift over but I'm reading between the lines that you are maintaining an old system built by (many) other people over the years.

Comment: @KolobCanyon I'm working on a 100 kLOC project - this is probably much smaller than yours, but it starts in five seconds from my Eclipse (no JSP, just JSON API; no deployment; a new process using embedded Jetty and killing the old one) and I find it way too slow. Your build times would make me quite the job.

Answer (score 6):

First, your hyperbole is a little off:

> You have to recompile **every** time you modify any line of code and pass the built EAR or WAR to the application server...

That depends entirely if you are using JSP or some other template library to build your application.  JSPs and most alternative templates allow you to edit in place and simply reload the page.  You just have to remember to copy those changes back to your repository.  But there's more, see below.

#### Why Java?

The biggest advantage that Java has over several other languages is the ecosystem surrounding it.  Whether you are building a Spring based application or doing your own thing, typically there is some API out there that is ready to support what you want to do.  The Java ecosystem has largely specialized on the server side.  Knowing you don't have to reinvent the wheel is a big boon.

Does Java have it's downsides?  Absolutely, but that applies to every computer language invented.  If you don't think so, you probably haven't built anything substantial with that language.

Blaming Java for a slow build is unfair.  Take some time to see if a better build tool can improve your build times.  If your build server is anemic, take time to figure out how to improve how it builds.  For example, I have a project that takes 2.5 minutes to build on my local machine to compile and create a deployment package from all the Java, C#, and Python pieces.  The same process on the build server takes 14 minutes.  A lot of that has to do with disk speed and it being an older server.  Fix the build.

#### Why not an interpreted language?

That really depends on the platform you are building and the team you have.  It's one thing to say you are using Ruby on Rails or PHP, etc. and another to find competent developers to support your app.  To be honest, the personnel issue is the one reason we migrated away from Ruby on Rails in a project.

That said, there are very few technical reasons not to use an interpreted language.  Typically it depends on if you can find all the support libraries you need for your particular domain.

- Pick the language that serves your needs best--including finding people
- Be careful to work in a way where you can commit working code to version control
- Be objective when selecting your platform.  An app is bigger than the framework or language it's built in.

#### They aren't mutually exclusive

For teams that use Java for web services and build Single Page Apps in JavaScript, they have the best of both worlds.  The user interface is built using one of the many Single Page App platforms with the advantage of being able to experiment quickly.  Meanwhile the web service part which doesn't typically change all that much can just be used.

In this world of microservices, it's becoming increasingly common to have a heterogeneous set of technologies.  For example, you might have a python based service to take advantage of the natural language support libraries for part of your app mixed in with Java based infrastructure pieces.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers haven't touched on the real reason Java became popular as a server side language.

When improvements in CPU performance started coming from additional cores rather than increasing clock speeds, applications needed to become multi-threaded to realize those performance gains. Java was one of the first languages *in common use* to introduce [high-level multithreading constructs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) that made writing highly concurrent applications relatively easy. Despite Java's (no longer deserved) reputation for being slow, it was evident that you could write multithreaded server applications faster and easier in Java than you could in nearly any other language. So that's what people did.

Comment: Add to that  non-blocking I/O which came out in version 1.4.  To Be Fair: all of those parallel constructs came from other languages first, and there was already a good set of libraries that implemented those concurrency tools since Java 1.3 days.  In 1.5 it actually became part of the standard library, and the JVM was tweaked to make the implementations of those constructs a bit more straight-forward.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Right.  Even before the concurrency libraries, the language had support for threads and the `synchronized` keyword.  I had the experience of attempting multi-threaded code in C++ before learning Java and the experience was like night and day.

Comment: @JimmyJames, true enough.  I do think that some of the things that came along in C# later are easier to work with than what Java has, but they had the benefit of learning from Java's implementation.  The rest of C#'s infrastructure (support libraries, etc) aren't as mature as Java's though.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch We've definitely moved on from `synchronized`.  I'm not completely convinced though about the C# implementation being intuitive or easy to follow.  I work with a team that ended up with deadlocks using `await` and they struggled to find the issue and resolve it.  I'm really excited by the [`coroutines`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html) concept as in Kotlin.

Comment: @JimmyJames at the risk of this going on too long, it just goes to show that all multithreaded code is hard.  Most common cause for deadlocks using `async`/`await` is calling a method that calls `Task.Await()` which throws a wrench in the whole thing.  If you use `async` you really do need to make it async all the way through the API.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I don't know the details of that specific issue but my concern is a feeling that people think that C# has made this easy but it's pretty opaque and kind of confusing to me and I've been writing multithreaded code for close to 2 decades.  It's kind of like the mistake (IMO) of allowing `synchronized` declarations on methods in Java.  It wasn't obvious what that meant and hiding crucial details isn't necessarily helping people in this context.  If you can't use an abstraction without understanding the implementation, it's not really an abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to recompile every time you modify any line of code and pass the built EAR or WAR to the application server

This is a process issue, and one that I didn't see answered above (including the voluminous comments).

Yes, for a production or QA deployment, you need to build a deployable artifact. This is a Good Thing, if only because it prevents well-meaning developers from logging into the server to make code changes.

But for development, you should be using an IDE (such as Eclipse or IntelliJ) to run the server locally.  You can change a single line of code and the IDE will incrementally compile and hot-swap the class into the running server. There are some cases where you will need to redeploy the WAR/EAR, but you should never need a full build to do that.

If you don't like IDEs, you can get much the same effect by working with "exploded" WAR/EAR files. This is painful, so I don't recommend it, but it definitely works: Java will let you recompile a single class (which was one of the things that I enjoyed about Java vs C++ in the late 90s), and both Tomcat and Jetty will automatically detect changes to JSPs.